# Better understanding of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Let $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N:\ |x|<1\}$ with $N\geq 2$ and $x_n$ a countable dense set in $B$. Consider the function $$u(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{i}|x-x_i|^{1/2}},\ \forall\ x\in B$$

By using, for example, the monotone convergence theorem, one can prove that $u$ is in $L^1(B)$ and therefore is finite almost everywhere.

I have some questions about this series:

I - Is there any way to prove that $u$ is finite almost everywhere only by means of, let's say, some test of convergence for series?

II - The series converges for every $x\neq x_i$?

Update: As @DanielFischer pointed out in the comments, II does not need to be true.

Thank you

Comment: II _may_ happen, I think, but in general does not hold. If among the dense set you have the points of a sequence converging "fast enough" to some $x \notin \{ x_i\}$, the series will diverge at that $x$.

Comment: I had thinked this too, but I wasn't sure of my example. I was thinking in including in such dense set a subsequence which satsifies (for some fixed $x$) $|x-x_{i_k}|=\frac{1}{2^{1_k}}$. Is this right @DanielFischer?

Comment: Yes, something like that would work.